How do I draw a single object to print from multiple materials?
I've been drawing objects in Blender, slicing in Cura, and printing them in a single material on an Ender3 V2.  So far so good.
I'm considering upgrading to a Bambu or Prusa with a multiple material handler.  I don't know what that workflow looks like.  Can I draw an object in Blender and use its material properties to indicate to the slicer that parts of the object are meant for different materials?  If not that, how?

I don't think the slicer would recognize the material properties from Blender (never worked with Blender, so I might be wrong) but you can do this quite easily in the Bambu Studio or Prusa Slicer.
You can either use the "painting tool" to paint different parts of the object (usually used for multicolour prints) using different materials, or you can export the model with the parts of different material as separate objects and then just set the filament for each. Again, I have never done Blender, but you can do this in Fusion360, where you export a .3MF project that has multiple objects.
